# Having trouble with java card game

Tags: java

Before I start, yes this is a homework assignment so obviously I am not asking for any answers but I would appreciate if anyone could help me in the right direction or give me some advice.

Ok so for an assignment I am making a game of black jack in java. Currently I have a Card class, a Deck Class, and my Main (CardGameTester). Right now I only am doing the game with one player (the user) so it's pretty basic. My main is quite messy and I could do with having a third class but I've decided to do it this way instead.

I'm getting several strange errors that I believe are me messing up my arraylists or something to do with the objects. If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it because I am quite stuck at the moment.

the errors I'm getting when I try to compile:

```
6 errors and 1 warning found:
--------------
*** Errors ***
--------------
File: E:\Documents\Java Files\Assignment 3\CardGameTester.java  [line: 17]
Error: The method add(Card) in the type java.util.ArrayList<Card> is not applicable for the arguments (Deck)
File: E:\Documents\Java Files\Assignment 3\CardGameTester.java  [line: 28]
Error: The method add(Card) in the type java.util.ArrayList<Card> is not applicable for the arguments (Deck)
File: E:\Documents\Java Files\Assignment 3\CardGameTester.java  [line: 35]
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Card to int
File: E:\Documents\Java Files\Assignment 3\Deck.java  [line: 15]
Error: The constructor Card() is undefined
File: E:\Documents\Java Files\Assignment 3\Deck.java  [line: 19]
Error: The method shuffle() is undefined for the type java.util.ArrayList<Card>
File: E:\Documents\Java Files\Assignment 3\Deck.java  [line: 30]
Error: c cannot be resolved
-------------
** Warning **
-------------
File: E:\Documents\Java Files\Assignment 3\Card.java  [line: 5]
Warning: The field Card.suits is never read locally
```

Here is Card.java

```
public class Card
{
  private int rankValue, suitValue;
  private String ranks[] = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds"};
  private String suits[] = {"Ace", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

  public Card(int rank, int suit)
  {
    rankValue = rank;
    suitValue = suit;
  }

  public String convertToString(int rank){
    return ranks[rank];
  }

  public void setRank(int rank){
    rankValue = rank;
  }

  public void setSuit(int suit){
    suitValue = suit;
  }

  public int getRank(){
    return rankValue;
  }

  public int getSuit(){
    return suitValue;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "Rank: " + rankValue + "Suit: " + suitValue;
  }
}
```

Here is Deck.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Deck
{
  private ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

  public Deck()
  {
    for(int a = 1; a <= 4; a++)
    {
      for(int b = 1; b <= 13; b++)
      {
        Card c = new Card();
        cards.add(c);
      }
    }
    cards.shuffle();
  }

  public void shuffle(){
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
  }

  public String deal(){
    int index = 0;
    cards.get(index);
    cards.remove(index);
    return "You have been dealt a: " + c.toString();
    index++;
  }
}
```

and here is my Main CardGametester.java:

```
public class CardGameTester
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    Deck d = new Deck();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Black Jack!\nWould you like to Start?");
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    if(input == "yes")
    {
      d.deal();
      hand.add(d);
    }

    String input2;

    while (input2 == "yes")
    {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Would you like to hit or stay?");
      input2 = keyboard.nextLine();
      d.deal();
      hand.add(d);
    }

    int total;

    for(int index = 0; index <= hand.size(); index++)
    {
      total = hand.get(index);
    }

    System.out.println("Your total value for you cards are: " + total);

    if(total <= 21){
      System.out.println("Congrats, you have won for not going over 21");
    }
    else
      {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you lose for going over 21");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are trying to add the entire `Deck` object to the list representing the hand, which is a list of `Card`s. If you can make `Deck.deal()` return a `Card` instead of a `String`, you could just do `hand.add(d.deal())`

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `==` when comparing Objects, like you are with the String input, instead use `"yes".equals(input2)`, as it will correctly compare the value of the object, rather than its reference. Placing the String literal first also makes the operation null safe (i.e. won't throw a `NullPointerException` if there's no input.

Comment: so instead of returning the value of the card in the deal method I should put that in the main? Also why is my c.toString method not working in the deal method? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `ArrayList` of `Card` but are trying to add a different type of `Deck`:

```
ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();

hand.add(d); // d = Deck
```

It would be better to return the index of the card in the `Deck.deal` to keep track of what card is in your `hand`.

Also, you are calling:

```
Card c = new Card();
```

but the constructor takes 2 arguments:

```
public Card(int rank, int suit)
```

There 2 errors here in the `deal` method:

```
...
return "You have been dealt a: " + c.toString();
index++;
...
```

Firstly as `Card` `c` will defined here. You could use:

```
Card c = cards.remove(index);
```

Secondly, no statements are allowed after `return` statements, so `index++` cannot appear here.

Next:

> Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Card to int

```
    total = hand.get(index);
      ^            ^
   int type     Card type
```

You are calling a non-existent method on `ArrayList`

```
cards.shuffle();
```

You already have this in a method so you could call

```
shuffle();
```

While not a compilation error, the use of `==` will cause your input Strings not to be evaluated correctly, so change

```
if (input == "yes")
```

to

```
if ("yes".equals(input))
```

Consider using [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) for managing the card rank & suit.

Comment: ok so I think I've fixed everything that you mentioned but I'm still not quite understanding what you're saying about about putting deck into my card arraylist. Are you saying that my deal method is the root of this problem?

Comment: I'm not saying that. Am saying that you need to keep track of what card is dealt out then you call `deal`. I wouldnt rely on the card index, the Card will have the info that you need (suit, rank), so return a `Card` object. Will leave the re-design as an exercise :)

Comment: alright I think I got that done correctly. Now lastly the only error I'm getting is on the part where "Type mismatch: cannot convert from card to int". Should I have created another card object to hold these values instead of the int I used?